# Hazelcast data transfer across nodes

Tags: hazelcast

If i have two hazelcast nodes in cluster node1 and node2

And if i insert `<key1,value1`> to an imap, and assuming node1 owns the `<key1,value1`>(primary) when node1 store data it converts `<key1, value1`> to bytes and saves it.

1)
 How is this data transferred to node2. When `<key1, value1`> are transferred as bytes to node2, would node2 save those bytes directly or are they deserialized to their respective types and then serialized back to bytes and saved?

2) And if new field is added to `value1` type and if node1 is restarted. When data is backed up from node2 to node1, would the bytes for `value1` be transferred to node1 
a) will that be desirialzed to the `value1` type in node1 which consists of new field and then serialized back to bytes and stored in node1 or
b) bytes from node2 for `value1` transferred to node1 stored directly without any conversion and those bytes doesn't consist of the field that was added to `value1` type?

Comment: 1) do you mean how does Hazelcast create backup on other nodes? Otherwise there is no reason for Hazelcast to transfer data to other members in the cluster unless you have an application that also has HC embedded into it, explicitly invokes a read operation.

Comment: 2) Not sure what your question is. Data gets serialized and deserialized every time it has to travel across members or member-client. Adding new field to an entry and restarting the node has no connection with each other. Take a look at Serialization and other relevant documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#serialization    http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#backing-up-maps

Answer (score 0):

In Hazelcast backup data is stored in binary form.

By default, backup is synchronous ie a PUT request will not return until the backup copy is updated. So the backup will not be out of sync.

Hazelcast support 3 in-memory storage formats BINARY (Default, speed of access)  , OBJECT (good for entry processors and queries)and NATIVE(Key and value stored off-heap). 
When the BINARY format is used, only a deserialization is required at the client BINARY, hence is faster.

If a value is stored in OBJECT format, a change in a returned value does not affect the stored instance. In this case, the returned instance is not the actual one but a clone. Therefore, changes made to an object after it is returned will not reflect on the actual stored data. Similarly, when a value is written to a map and the value is stored in OBJECT format, it will be a copy of the put value. Therefore, changes made to the object after it is stored will not reflect the stored data.